# How to send an image onclick in a chat application?

Tags: java, android

I have an application which includes chatting, I'm able to send texts however what I want to achieve is to send images whenever I click on one of the images in a gridview, so using the below code whenever I click on an image it displays in the chat a text however it's not showing as an image at all, can you please tell me what do I need to do to achieve this

smiles_items_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/smile_image_view"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

BottomSheetDialog_Smiles.java

```
public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final int[] mThumbIds;
String[] mThumbIdsString = null;

    public ImageAdapter2(Context c, int[] mThumbIds ,  String[] mThumbIdsString) 
    {
     mContext = c;
     this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
     this.mThumbIdsString = mThumbIdsString;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length & mThumbIdsString.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public class Holder {
        ImageView img;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, 
    ViewGroup parent) {

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);
        null);

        holder.img = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);
        holder.img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


        gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new 
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            Drawable drawable;

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
            int i, long l) {
                JSONDictionary imageChat = new JSONDictionary();
                LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)view;
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(0);
                imageView.getDrawable();
                imageChat.put("message", imageView);
                Communicator.getInstance().emit("new chat message", 
                imageChat);
            }
        });

        return grid;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have less than 50 reputation so can't write comment right now , but your question is not clear , where you want to send the image ?? if you have the path of the images inside grid you can use them where ever you want

second instead of using BaseAdapter and the default list you can use the new library called RecyclerView it's more powerfull and very easy

**UPDATED**

ok this is you code after update

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, 
ViewGroup parent) {

    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);
    null);

    holder.img = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);
    holder.img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    holder.img.settag(String.valueof(mThumbIds[position]))


    gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
        int i, long l) {
            JSONDictionary imageChat = new JSONDictionary();
            LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)view;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(0);
            imageView.getDrawable();
            imageChat.put("message", imageView.gettag());
            Communicator.getInstance().emit("new chat message", 
            imageChat);
        }
    });

    return grid;

}
```

your problem is you put the imageview so the text is actually not the image but the address of the image

Comment: I want to send the image to the chat as well as to the server

Comment: see this link https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594 using volley library you can send image to server

Comment: and if you want use the image in the chat , you must have your image path to use it where ever you want such as your chat activity

Comment: Let me explain in a clearer way, so I click on one of the images in a gridview, whatever the image I click on I want it to be sent in the chat, forget about the server now, let's just sort out sending the image to the chat

Comment: ok as you wish , let as solve your problem step by step ,
you have a chat activity right ? then how you go to the gridView image and the grid images from where you get them ?

Comment: Okay so I have a chat activity, inside the chat activity there is a button on the right hand side, when I click this button it displays all the images that I can send,,,so I want to send it onclick, in my code you'll find the gridiew in xml

Comment: the images you get them from drawable folder in your project or from your device ?

Comment: the image is from drawable folder, however when I press on the image it displays some text

Comment: ok when you set the images in the adapter give tag for each imageview mThumbIds[position]  so when click the image return the tag 
i will update my answer so if it work for you please make it accepted

Comment: I've tried the above code however it's coming up with 2131166894 but not the image itself !

Comment: ok this number is the resource(drawable) id then you can use it to get the drawable image it self

Comment: must be write imageView.setImageResource(resource_id) that come from imageView.gettag() but am not sure very will